# Need div to fill 100% of width - 30 pixels (other div in same container)

Tags: html, css

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/vAeLu/

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="panel-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="bottom">
                <div class="update">Updating in: <div class="seconds">5</div> seconds</div>
                <div class="time"></div>
                <div class="date"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

#panel {
    width: 21.25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0794ea;
}

#panel-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5.5%;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.update {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #006699;
    text-align: center;
    height: 39px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.seconds {
    display: inline;
}

.time {
    float: left;
}

.date {
    float: right;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#right-bar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #006699;
    float: right;
}
```

I need the panel update box to fill 100% of the width - the 30 pixels that the border/scroll div I've created has.

How can I do this with the current code I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/6cEfU/) should do the trick.

I applied your border to the `.panel` element and applied `box-sizing: border-box;` so the border is within the 100% width.

**Result**

[image: 100% Width with Border]

Comment: If you want/need to keep the `#right-bar` in there you can use this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/99TfD/

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 property `calc` was deigned for this if IE7-8 support isn't required.

`width: calc(100% - 30px);`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can have a cross-browser solution with both % and px calculations in CSS.

Here's a jQuery solution instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('#panel-content .update').each({
        $(this).width( $(this).width()-30 );
    });
});
```